# Loading images from the server, memory leak

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing an app, which we need to keep loading images from the server, and whenever we load an image from the server, it reserve a chunk of memory, and never release it until the app crashes(memory full), as I research about it, it seems that Unity3d generate this garbage in memory when converting an image to Texture2D. but the problem is that it never delete this garbage.

Comment: How are you loading your textures? Do you do something like "tex = Resources.Load(name);" or "tex = Instantiate(Resources.Load(name));" I believe for releasing memory you need to use the Instantiate function.

Comment: No, am downloading these from the server, so I am using WWW class.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/38246/www-texture-access-takes-a-long-time.html) it may be rescue you.